# Trying to create a simple pile-of-sand type texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

I'm currently trying (and failing) to create a close-to-realistic pile of ground coffee beans. I put a blue annotation to indicate roughly what I'm trying to accomplish, and I got pretty close with the nodes shown.

The problem is this setup doesn't rough up the edges of the gradient into values way closer to 0 and 1, instead of the current soft gradient look shown here, and obviously is void of any kind of roughness.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do it with material only, or are you open to using geometry nodes to instance "ground coffee bits" (objects) all over a surface. If you're looking for material only, are you using cycles (with or without displacement), or eevee?

Answer (score 8):

*Musgrave Texture* is a pretty good candidate for breaking up an outline like this, since it outputs values between -1 and 1 it won't offset your coordinates.  On average everything will be centered around the same point.

You can use *MixRGB* on coordinate vectors and it will operate on each channel as though it were RGB, and you can use it as a vector input afterwards with no problem.

[image]

To get a harder gradient you just need to move the white stop on your *Color Ramp* further towards black.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do some touches manually.

Try editing the texture "by hand"... Just like if you were making a PBR texture or drawing... The darker a color is, the deeper it will look. And the lighter the color is, the more popped-out it will look...

For example, paint with a darker shade (of the same color of the sand) for a deeper effect in a certain area, or a lighter shade than the original color for a bumpy/ popped-out effect, and use a blend brush to mix the colors together.

If you don't understand much of coloring, I suggest watching some tutorials about color blending/mixing and shading, since it's the same process whether you're painting a texture or a drawing...

Here are 2 tutorials that might help and you don't need Photoshop to follow it, since the coloring process is the same in any program:

- https://youtu.be/5L8BBVNBheM
- https://youtu.be/e-Zsgv993Os

And for a more grainy effect, you can try adding some noise to the texture if you like.